# How many objects can I send to Akamai edge server for purging?

Tags: rest, akamai

Akamai recently released their REST API for handling purge from edge servers.

I'm making a function/method to reach out to that API and invalidate the cache of inputted object in our storage.

The **[docs](https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/docs/index.html)** say that it's possible to pass multiple objects to the request (see the Purge Request section). They don't say however, **how many** objects I can pass into it.

I'm talking about potentially thousands of objects that need to be purged in one call, does anyone know exactly how many objects can I pass per call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10,000 is max queue length.

If you have more than that, you should implement api call to check queue status and then queue more objects when there is room.

Comment: The idea of a queue is to abstract the the need of me looking to see if there's room, that's hte job of the queue! A bit silly if you ask me, but this is the correct answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: In addition, you can send up to 500 objects in a single request, at least with the new {OPEN} V2 CCU API